# Change the font in the Android Studio editor or IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, fonts, editor

I think the title is already clear enough.

I have been able to change the font for my editor through accessing:

`Preferences > Editor > Color Scheme > Font`

But happens that some of my fonts are not available there; although a lot of them they are. This happens to me in this machine with the `FightingSpirit` font. Not that I want to use it but it's one where the issue happens.

At work I have added ligatures to the `Menlo` font using an open source project and it doesn't show up. I've tried disabling `Show only monospaced fonts` and although more fonts show up, some of the fonts still are not available.

Is there any fix for this, is it impossible for some fonts or am I doing something wrong?

#### EDIT

I have been able to set that ligaturized font to some of my editors and terminal, so the font is not corrupted and does work.

Comment: IDE has a filter for fonts and will display only those that can show specific glyphs used in the code (letters, numbers, etc). The fonts that don't show are probably missing some glyphs or they are not compatible with the JVM font rendering engine.

Comment: But I am able to choose the font `Menlo` without ligatures. And I'm also able to choose the font `Fira Code` (and the open source project imports this font's ligatures to the new font). So it really doesn't remove any glyphs or anything. Why shouldn't display the new font that is a combination of both that the IDE considers "displayable"?

Comment: You can study/debug the logic in `com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.FontInfo` to see why your specific font is not listed.

Comment: Do you have a link that I could actually use?

Comment: [Here is the link](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/platform-impl/src/com/intellij/openapi/editor/impl/FontInfo.java#L158).

Comment: Thank you I'll try to dig into that

Comment: Just for people to know; there's no real answer to this question. In some upgraded version of Android Studio and IntelliJ IDEA it began to accept my custom font so I could choose it :shrug:

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some IDE updates the font showed up so the problem fixed itself